# Incorrect signature error. Query record id by name <Name is unique data>

Tags: apex, class

this code allows users to upload CSV files to update data to Salesforce. What I want is, how to make users can update existing data without inserting record ID as well to update data.
I think I can query the record id based on the name (the name is a unique value). But I am not sure how to do that

```
public class UpdateIncentiveFile {
    
    public string nameFile{get;set;}
    public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
    String[] filelines = new String[]{};
    List<Lala__c> accstoupload;
    List<id> listOfId;
    
    /***This function reads the CSV file and inserts records into the Lala__c object. ***/
    public Pagereference ReadFile()
    {
        try{
                //Convert the uploaded file which is in BLOB format into a string
                nameFile =blobToString( contentFile,'ISO-8859-1');
                
                //Now sepatate every row of the excel file
                filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
                
                //Iterate through every line and create a Lala__c record for each row
                accstoupload = new List<Lala__c>();
                for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
                {
                    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
                    
                    
                    Lala__c a = new Lala__c();
                    //a.id= listOfId;
                    a.Name = inputvalues[0];
                    a.HOT__c = inputvalues[1];
                    a.OIC__c = inputvalues[2];       
                    a.Year__c = inputvalues[3];
                    a.January__c = double.valueOf(inputvalues[4]);
                    a.February__c = double.valueOf(inputvalues[5]);
                    a.March__c = double.valueOf(inputvalues[6]);
                    
                    listOfId.add([select id from Lala__c where name = :inputvalues[0]]);
                    a.Id = listOfId[0];
                    accstoupload.add(a);
                    System.debug('The value is accstoupload: ' + accstoupload);
                }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
                 ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured reading the CSV file-- '+e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
         }       
        //Finally, insert the collected records
        try{
            update accstoupload;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured inserting the records'+e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
        }    
        return null;
    }
   
   /**** This function sends back to the visualforce page the list of account records that were inserted ****/ 
    public List<Lala__c> getuploadedAccounts()
    {
        if (accstoupload!= NULL)
            if (accstoupload.size() > 0)
                return accstoupload;
            else
                return null;                    
        else
            return null;
    }  

    public static String blobToString(Blob input, String inCharset){
        String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(input);
        System.assertEquals(0, hex.length() & 1);
        final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1;
        String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
        for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
            bytes[i] =  hex.mid(i << 1, 2);
        return EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), inCharset);
    }

}
```

This is the error

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(List<Lala__c>) from the type List<Id>
```

in this line

```
listOfId.add([select id from Incentive__c where name = :inputvalues[0]]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SOQL is actually inside a loop which violates the Apex Best Practice #2 [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices)

Actually you don't need a query to get the record ID in the first place, since your Name field is unique, and Name field usually has the `idLookup` attribute as true, which means you can use `upsert` DML based on the Name field as the external ID.
Checkout the [Database.upsert()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_upsert_2) method.

```java
for (...) {
    Lala__c a = new Lala__c();
    a.Name = inputvalues[0];
    ...
    accstoupload.add(a)
}

Database.upsert(accstoupload, Lala__c.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, this method does not exist. `add` will add single element to the list. You need to use `addAll` method.

Comment: When I put addAll, I received this error
`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addall(List<Lala__c>) from the type List<Id>`

Comment: that is because you have list of Ids and want to add to this list a LaLa__c records.

Comment: if you want to add just ids of those LaLa__c records you need to iterate the query result and add the ids one by one